# How can Sage Kashyap marry daughters of Daksha, even they are parallel cousins?

Tags: marriage, indra, kashyapa

I found a really interesting discussion named [Father of Indra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/father-of-indra), which I never thought about the birth of Indra and Sun god. Credits to the user.

Here my question is, according to `sanatana dharma` it is known fact that a person is not supposed to marry his sister. But it contradicts when we relate this with the story of Sage Kashyap marrying 13 daughters of prajapati Dakhsa.

Kashyap, son of Marichi who is one of the mind-born son of Lord Brahma. And Prajapati Daksha, son of Lord Brahma. As the relation between Marichi and Daksha is a kind of brother relation, so Kashyap can be considered as son of Daksha and eventually Daksha's daughters should be Kashyap's sisters.

Though Marichi might be a mind-born son, somehow they both relate as brothers. Then, how does it related with Kashyap's marriage.

So, how different is the births of Marichi and Daksha?

Comment: Well, even today there's cousin marriage in India.

Comment: But I don't think it is, brother and sister marriage. Cousin might be something like `in-laws`, and not brother and sister right..

Comment: Well, Kashyap and Aditi aren't literal siblings, they're first cousins.  I have lots of aunts and uncles who are married to their first cousins.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What exactly do you mean by cousins?

Comment: First cousins are people whose parents are siblings.  So since Kashyap's father and Aditi's father are brothers, Kashyap and Aditi are first cousins.  I have lots of family members who are married to their first cousins.

Comment: Really!!! I couldn't imagine this. Can you give any other instincts of this kind(within Indian mythology)

Comment: Yeah, Arjuna married Krishna's sister Subadra, who was his first cousin.  (Arjuna's mother Kunti and Subhadra's father Vasudeva were brother and sister.)  And Abhimanyu married Balarama's daughter, who was his first cousin.  (Balarama and Abhimanyu's mother Subhadra were brother and sister.)  First-cousin marriages are still common in South India, by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22854/discussion-between-giri-and-keshav-srinivasan).

Comment: Yama and yamuna were also twin and married. Brahma married to his daughter.

Comment: @AnkitSharma yama and Yamuna didn't marry, the story condemned incest same with story of brahma. The saraswati being brahma's wife are puranic stories, the Vedas don't mention it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, the word 'first-cousin' is very misrepresentative in that it means both paternal first-cousin and maternal first-cousin. paternal first-cousins have same gotra, so inter-marriage not allowed. maternal first-cousins have different gotra so inter-marriage is allowed.

Comment: Bharadwaja gothra men can marry from same gothra? (due to an exception given of their large numbers, finding suitors from other gothras difficult ?) Some priests even refuse to conduct same gothra marriages.

Comment: First you cannot apply human rules to godly beigns second.. brahma first creation is different in every aspect, Daskha is king kshatriya, Marichi is Rishi.. so both are different in gothra pravara or jathi.. in that sense they are not cousin,, one more point here if call the whole world is related in  one sense all are brothers and sister because there great great inifintely great grand father is brahma his father is Narayana so all brothers and sister in one sense,, how is this relationship.. so to think like that is foolish

Comment: Convenience of numbers in population. These happened when at the beginning marriage possibilities are very limited. On the other hand when too many become available in one gothra, at times same gothra is made permissible.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you see cross cousin marriages are allowed in rare cases, during the start of human race, this was allowed and we can conclude it is an exception because manu in matsya purana curiously asks Lord matsya that how could lord brahma's sons marry in same gotra, to this the answer was that it was an exception, and when progeny was enough gotra system was placed.

This is also practised in South India in rare-exceptional cases

> Baudhayana Dharmasutra, PRASNA I, ADHYÂYA 1, KANDIKÂ 2 declares that
>   people from South India can marry with the daughter of their maternal
>   uncle.
>
> We will explain those (peculiar) to the south.
>
> They are, to eat in the company of an uninitiated person, to eat in
>   the company of one's wife, to eat stale food, **to marry the daughter of
>   a maternal uncle or of a paternal aunt.**
>
> But there is one condition that, the above practices can be followed
>   only in prevailed country.
>
> He who follows (these practices) in any other country than where they
>   prevail, commits sin.

Well, manu's laws are considered foremost among laws as they are talked in purva mimansa sutras also that they ban marriage among same gotra.

The cross cousin marriage is allowed only as an exception if there is not enough humans to have cross progeny.

**Why was this exception allowed for first humans, South Indians etc?**

Well my guess is because of low population, according to South Indians agastya was father of Dravidian languages, who was also a Vedic rishi, during those times most of the South India was forest and very thinly populated so it was accepted to have progeny, through cross cousins, rishis to keep the humans going, allowed it, the practice is still followed although the population has grown enough.

As for first humans it was allowed as an exception because of once again low density of humans that time.

**but why for subhadra and Arjuna?**

Well, Arjuna and subhadra had gandharva vivah, I highly doubt kings cared for gotra-Varna when doing gandharva vivah, these are allowed for them as an exception while most works say that one should have arranged marriage ideally!

Arranged marriages do care about- astrology, Varna, gotra, kundali etc.

Hinduism doesn't ban anything, what leads to good is moral, so while the long cross gotra marriages are considered ideal, the cross cousin marriage is allowed under extreme exceptions due to population density, personal opinions etc.

Comment: the word 'first-cousin' is very misrepresentative in that it means both paternal first-cousin and maternal first-cousin. paternal first-cousins have same gotra, so inter-marriage not allowed. maternal first-cousins have different gotra so inter-marriage is allowed. e.g. if there are 2 brothers, and one has a son and other has a daughter, they belong to same gotra. whereas if there is a brother & sister, and they have a son & daughter, they are of different gotra

Answer (score 1):

I think ,marriage between blood relations is common in ancient times..
Not only this story,got many story like this..such lord chandra married with 27 daughters of prasuti..that means he married his own aunts..lord chandra is son of anusuya..anusuya is daughter of devahuti..prasuti and devahuti is sisters..that means the 27 daughters of prasuti is cousin sisters for anusuya..

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.  (You can quote the Srimad Bhagavatam, for instance.)

Comment: Gawd, I never thought  of  it  in this angle... This is seriously gross..

Comment: The word is "kinship studies" , in anthropology and "Dravidian kinship" , the term coined by its discovery of the practices in south india, has since been found in some other cultures as well, such as in Egypt, and is now considered a distinct seventh kinship.

Comment: @Surya, the word 'first-cousin' is very misrepresentative in that it means both paternal first-cousin and maternal first-cousin. paternal first-cousins have same gotra, so inter-marriage not allowed. maternal first-cousins have different gotra so inter-marriage is allowed. e.g. if there are 2 brothers, and one has a son and other has a daughter, they belong to same gotra. whereas if there is a brother & sister, and they have a son & daughter, they are of different gotra

Comment: @ram Yes, but doesn't that rule apply to people of a single generation? Here Chandra seems to be marrying the generation before him.

Comment: @Surya, Chandra married the 27 daughters of Daksha Prajapati. And I'm not sure which takes precedence - generation or age. what if their "aunts" are younger than him ?

Answer (score 1):

In vedic cosmology there are many categories of living beings i.e. devas, rushis, humans, animals, nagas, rakshas, daityas, prajapatis etc.

Marriage rules given in dharma shastras/smritis are for humans only. They don't always apply to other beings like rishis, nagas etc.

kashyap, daksha etc. fall under the categories of rushis, prajapatis and hence this marriage rule doesn't apply for them